# WCF ServiceHost namespace prefix not defined

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, namespaces

Im hosting a SOAP ServiceHost, and the client is sending a specific message.

The service is responding a 500 Internal Server Error as it is not capable of decoding the SOAP message. The fault reason is:

**Reason**: "Error deserializing body of request message for operation GetStreamUri"

**InnerException**: "Namespace prefix **'onv'** is not defined"

To check what was happening we compared the messages arriving with those parsed by the servicehost.

We captured the message with Wireshark:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:onv="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" 
xmlns:media="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <!-- security stuff -->
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <media:GetStreamUri>
            <media:StreamSetup xsi:type="onv:StreamSetup">
                <onv:Stream>RTP-Unicast</onv:Stream>
                <onv:Transport xsi:type="onv:Transport">
                    <onv:Protocol>UDP</onv:Protocol>
                </onv:Transport>
            </media:StreamSetup>
            <media:ProfileToken>cs_videoProfileTK_000</media:ProfileToken>
        </media:GetStreamUri>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And the we captured what the servicehost received with a Message Inspector:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
        <!-- security stuff -->
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <media:GetStreamUri xmlns:media="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl">
            <media:StreamSetup xsi:type="onv:StreamSetup" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <onv:Stream xmlns:onv="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">RTP-Unicast</onv:Stream>
                <onv:Transport xsi:type="onv:Transport" xmlns:onv="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">
                    <onv:Protocol>UDP</onv:Protocol>
                </onv:Transport>
            </media:StreamSetup>
            <media:ProfileToken>cs_videoProfileTK_000</media:ProfileToken>
        </media:GetStreamUri>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the namespace parser detects the 'onv' prefix, and assigns it to

```
<onv:Stream xmlns:onv="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema">RTP-Unicast</onv:Stream>
```

but the issue is that 'onv' namespace is defined just after being used in the xsi:type attribute

```
<media:StreamSetup xsi:type="onv:StreamSetup" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

It seems that the XMLSerializer is not doing a good job with namespaces being used in attributes. Is there any solution or workaround using message formatters or inspectors?

**Edit**
Generated code from WSDL.

```
// StreamSetup class
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema")]
public partial class StreamSetup : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private StreamType streamField;

    //ommited

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public StreamType Stream {
        get {
            return this.streamField;
        }
        set {
            this.streamField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Stream");
        }
    }

    // ommited
}

// StreamType class
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema")]
public enum StreamType {

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("RTP-Unicast")]
    RTPUnicast,

    // ommited
}

// Get Stream URI Method/Operation
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl/GetStreamUri", ReplyAction="*")]
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults=true)]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(ConfigurationEntity))]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(DeviceEntity))]
[return: System.ServiceModel.MessageParameterAttribute(Name="MediaUri")]
ONVIF.MediaUri GetStreamUri(ONVIF.StreamSetup StreamSetup, string ProfileToken);
```

Comment: Both the Wireshark and Inspector outputs are valid.  The error must be in your definitions of your classes or the code.  Don't blame the input being wrong.  In most cases namespaces are applied only to elements, in some cases attributes also require namespaces.  Without seeing your code and classes I can't explain the exact cause of the error.

Comment: Edited to add generated code. Isnt the Inspector output invalid, due to the use of "onv" in the <media:StreamSetup xsi:type="onv:StreamSetup"> element, before defining it in the <onv:Stream> element?

Comment: Read the error message :  "Error deserializing body of request message for operation GetStreamUri".  You don't have a class for "GetStreamUri" element.

Comment: GetStreamUri is not a class, it's an operation/method. I'll edit the question to include the method

Comment: GetStreaUri needs to be a class since it is an an element tag in the xml.